# How do I stop git from packing tag annotations when there is no tty?

Tags: git

I have a Git tag annotation that reads:

```
Release 1.0
   - Fixes issue 1
   - Fixes issue 2
```

However, if I read this information in a script using `$()` where there is no TTY, Git will pack it all into one line:

```sh
MSG=$(git tag -l --format '%(contents)' release-1.00)
echo $MSG
```

Result:

```
Release 1.0 - issue 1 - issue 2
```

**How do I get it to output the original annotation?**

---

Without putting it into the script, the output of exactly the same command is the contents of the annotation exactly as is was created:

```sh
git tag -l --format '%(contents)' release-1.00
```

Result:

```
Release 1.0
   - Fixes issue 1
   - Fixes issue 2
```

---

FYI: Using `git tag -n99 release-1.00` does the same thing. I went hunting through the Git source code to try to answer my question and in the meantime discovered that `-n99` is internally translated into `--format '$(contents:lines=99)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the behavior of echo.

Instead of this:

```
MSG=$(git tag -l --format '%(contents)' release-1.00)
echo $MSG
```

followings will be good:

```
MSG=$(git tag -l --format '%(contents)' release-1.00)
echo "$MSG"
```

Comment: I didn't even think to play with the echo. I was just using it to debug that I was getting the right information at that point in development.